# Error in writing bibliography by using bibtex file

Tags: bibtex

Help me on writing references in an Article by using bibtex file.

The following command is not working in texstudio, where References is the name of the bibtex file & exists in same folder as .tex file:-

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliography{References}

\begin{document}
\newpage
\bibliography{References} 
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\end{document}
```

After compiling the error is as below:-

```
Missing \begin{document}. \begin{thebibliography}{}
Empty `thebibliography' environment
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have to put the `\bibliography{References}` only where you want the bibliography. And you can't have that before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: You have to use at least one `\cite{}`. Also, run `bibtex`.